# Where can I find a comprehensive guide to running the NIST SP800-90B_EntropyAssessment?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator, nist, trng

I am already using the 2 they suggest :

https://github.com/usnistgov/SP800-90B_EntropyAssessment https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90B.pdf

but, here is where I run into issues, I have a a file with 1,000,000 bits, what's the right format for the input? they don't state that, should it be a python tuple, or a list, or a just 1s and 0s continuously.

I ran the iid test, and got a score for H_original, but there are no guidelines that I can understand that state exactly how good or bad that is.

I have worked with Dieharder before and it was much clearer, they had a list of tests and gave a clear indication of whether you passed or failed the tests.

Help me out here, trying to test how random a bunch of 1s and 0s are.

Comment: CAUTION: Dieharder, SP800-90B_EntropyAssessment etc.. can demonstrate beyond doubt that a sequence of bits is not uniformly random. But they are essentially useless to assess that a sequence of bits is suitable for cryptographic use, unless these bits are from a source of well-defined nature and NOT post-conditioned cryptographically. Many publications on cryptography nevertheless use results of such tests on the output of a cryptographic construction as an argument for the security of that construction. Such a deep flaw often causes rejection by serious publications on cryptography.

Comment: @fgrieu Itsy bitsy thing though.  90B is not a randomness test. It's a min.entropy measurement. So there's no pass or fail. ANY sequence of bits of ANY distribution is acceptable to those tests. It just spits out a Min. entropy value. (Which is naff for the `ea_non_iid` test.)

Comment: @fgrieu what do you recommend I look into to actually assess the quality of randomness? If those tests are good enough, what should I be looking into?

also, where can I read more about  "post-conditioned cryptography", I don't know what that is.

Comment: To actually assess that randomness is of crypto quality, there is no substitute to analyzing _how_ it is generated. Again, no automated tool applied to the generated randomness can do this; they can only detect some of the worst kinds of cryptographic weaknesses. It is easy to make a simple PRNG that passes all tests, yet is insecure. For post-conditioning, see [SP800-90A](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf). For context about use, see [this](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Publications/sp/800-90c/draft/documents/sp800_90c_second_draft.pdf#page=18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too difficult:-

- Format has to be a pure binary file. No Python nothin'.
- Any other formats will produce a valid $H_{\infty}$ estimate, but will have been treated as pure binary. So e.g. 32 bit ASCII integers followed by a carriage return will be interpreted in the strictest binary sense, symbol by symbol.
- Expect $H_{\infty} \approx$ 7.9 bits/byte to use the samples directly for encryption.
- The samples must have 256 unique symbols in order to use them directly for encryption.
- $H_{\infty}$ and the number of unique symbols can be anything if you're going to use a downstream randomness extractor.
- Add the -v argument for something to watch while you wait (and show the tests).
- Failed tests have a star next to them.
- Be mindful of fgrieu's comment to you.

Good luck.

Comment: okay, this is what I understood
1. It should preferably be a binary file.
2. 7,9 out of 8 is an excellent score
3. I need the generator to generate 256 unique symbols
4. I will use -v and keep fgrieu's comment in mind. 

How do you know all this? Is there some guide I could follow that will guide me through running this. I am quite new to this space as you might have guessed from the question.

Comment: @VardhanMahajan Well the documents you've mentioned are about it.

Comment: Further to that you're relying on experience :-)  Although please don't overthink 90B. It's just measuring a specific quantity.  You'll understand when running with the -v option. There are real world examples [here](http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/matahari/analysis/) illustrating how 90B fits into a design.